# If Statement Using JavaScript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want this div displayed on my page whenever there is a "Y" in the database.

```
<div style="width:100%; height:41px; position:fixed; bottom:0px; background:#184888;     padding:22px 0 0 15px;  bottom:0px; z-index:9997; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;" id="hide">
<div id="message" style="z-index:9998;">  </div>
```

How would I make it so that the div is displayed and not displayed without refreshing the page. Basically I have to see if it is a "Y" in the database, and if it is, display the div. If an "N" is in the database do not display the div, using JavaScript.

I am currently using this function to see check the database for a value.

```
$('div#checkcheck').load('../bar/check.php/check.php');
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass an anonymous function to your jQuery load. This will be able to catch the value from check.php

```
$('div#checkcheck').load('../bar/check.php/check.php', function(response) {
  //do something with that response
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Send an ajax request to your server. Let your php code check for the 'Y' in database.
Your server call will return a json.

Use that json in javascript to check for 'Y' or'N' and then show/hide your div.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get('../bar/check.php/check.php', function(response) {
    $('div#checkcheck')[response === 'Y' ? 'show' : 'hide']();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.getJSON('../bar/check.php/check.php', function(res){
    if(res === 'Y')
    {
        $('div').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('div').hide();
    }
});
```